# How to access a Dataset column via a variable

Tags: dataset, filtering

I want to pick values of varying columns from a dataset, eg. from the Dataset in the documentation

```
dataset = Dataset[{
   <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> "x", "c" -> {1}|>,
   <|"a" -> 2, "b" -> "y", "c" -> {2, 3}|>,
   <|"a" -> 3, "b" -> "z", "c" -> {3}|>,
   <|"a" -> 4, "b" -> "x", "c" -> {4, 5}|>,
   <|"a" -> 5, "b" -> "y", "c" -> {5, 6, 7}|>,
   <|"a" -> 6, "b" -> "z", "c" -> {}|>}]
```

then

```
attribute = "b"
```

I'm now searching something like

```
dataset[Select[b=="x"]], resp dataset[Select[#b=="x"&]]
```

This is clearly not working but I think is good enough to show what I am searching for

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following @Syed, maybe something like this

```
{attr, val} = {"b", "x"};
Select[dataset, #[attr] == val &]
```

[image]

Also due to @Syed, there is this one

```
Query[Select[#[attr] == val &]]@dataset
```

And, we can't leave out

```
Cases[dataset, _[___, Rule[attr, val], ___]]  (* eyesore *)

Cases[dataset, KeyValuePattern[attr -> val]]  (* legible *)
```

Comment: Learned something new here. Could you please refer me to a doc page where I can find more about the `#[ ]` syntax. Or could you perhaps elaborate how to combine slots with string patterns?

Comment: @Syed  I wanted to add this answer as a comment to your answer, but I thought it was too long.  I happened to find the `#["name"]` form of `Slot` in the Details section of the [docs for Slot](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slot.html#Details).  Your answer also showed how to use `Query`.  Please, undelete your answer so it can be accepted as the better, more complete one and feel free to add the `#["name"]` form to your answer.  You led me to it.

Comment: Thanks for the link and for the offer. Very kind of you. I think you can add the `Query` variant to your answer with proper syntax. I enjoyed experimenting for 20 minutes, and exploring with `FullForm` etc. before giving up.

Comment: Thanks for this hint, I was not so lucky to find the "Slot-Trick".  BTW a lot of this Dataset operations are not really self explanatory ....